# How do I use std::tr1::mem_fun in Visual Studio 2008 SP1?

Tags: c++, std, tr1, mem-fun

The *VS2008 SP1* documentation talks about **`std::tr1::mem_fun`**.

So why, when I try and use **`std::tr1::mem_fun`**, why do I get this compile error?:

```
'mem_fun' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
```

At the same time, I can use **`std::tr1::function`** without problems.

Here is the sample code I am trying to compile, which is supposed to call `TakesInt` on an instance of `Test`, via a `function<void (int)>`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct Test { void TakesInt(int i) { std::cout << i; } };

void _tmain() 
{
    Test* t = new Test();

    //error C2039: 'mem_fun' : is not a member of 'std::tr1'
    std::tr1::function<void (int)> f =
        std::tr1::bind(std::tr1::mem_fun(&Test::TakesInt), t);
    f(2);
}
```

I'm trying to use the tr1 version of **`mem_fun`**, because when using **`std::mem_fun`** my code doesn't compile either! I can't tell from the compiler error whether the problem is with my code or whether it would be fixed by using tr1's **`mem_fun`**. That's C++ compiler errors for you (or maybe it's just me!).

---

### Update: Right. The answer is to spell it correctly as mem_fn!

However when I fix that, the code still doesn't compile.

Here's the compiler error:

```
error C2562: 
'std::tr1::_Callable_obj<_Ty,_Indirect>::_ApplyX' :
  'void' function returning a value
```

Comment: What is the compile error you get when you use std::mem_fun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
std::tr1::function<void (int)> f =
    std::tr1::bind(std::tr1::mem_fn(&Test::TakesInt), t, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);
f(2);
```

The binder requires the int argument. So you have to give it a placeholder which stands for the integer argument that the generated function object needs.

Btw: I'm not sure whether you already know this or not. But you don't need that mem_fn for this. Just change it to

```
std::tr1::function<void (int)> f =
    std::tr1::bind(&Test::TakesInt, t, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);
f(2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I had just worked out where _1 came from and was coming back to update my question with the fix.

Comment: Okay, all answers got me nearer to a solution, so I had trouble picking which one to accept. But unfortunately I can only accept one. I think this one shows the cleanest way to implement what I want, using the tr1 additions, but I up-voted all others. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on either TR1 or VS2008, but a quick googling suggests that the function you're looking for is std::tr1::mem_fn instead. (At least, that's what Boost calls it in their [TR1 implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_tr1/subject_list.html#boost_tr1.subject_list.mem_fn), and that's how it's detailed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#mem_fn).)

I'm not sure why you're getting a compile error with the old version of mem_fun though. If you post the compiler's message about that, it might help us figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To use mem_fun like that you need to fully specify all the template arguments (as mem_fun is a class and automatic template parameter deduction is not done on classes). Also mem_fun only has a default constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Not having the full class definition it is hard to get correct.
But my best bet at what you wanted would be this: (or something close)

```
 std::tr1::mem_fun<Test,void (Test::*)(Test*),&Test::TakesInt>()
```

What I think you are looking for is mem_fn(). This is a function that returns an object of type mem_fun. Because it is a function automatic template parameter deduction is done.

```
  std::tr1::mem_fn(&Test::TakesInt)
```

To solve the second problem use: std::bind1st()

```
  f=    std::bind1st(std::tr1::mem_fn(&Test::TakesInt), t);
```

Comment: struct Test is fully defined in the sample code. I've updated the question with the compiler error I get when I use mem_fn.